# Auto width css blur

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the width value to all text (view pic) for all screen, but I can't do it..
[image]

You can see the blur doesn't take all text. This is my HTML and CSS code :

```css
.conseil-card {
  background: #ffffff 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 12px #00000014;
  border-radius: 15px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  color: #212529;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  text-align: left;
  font: normal normal normal 16px/22px Poppins;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 8px;
}

.conseil-card p {
  text-align: left;
}

.conseil-card svg {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

.conseil-card-title {
  color: #8d9899;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.conseil-card-pack {
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.conseil-card-pack::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 107px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: transparent linear-gradient(180deg, #ffffff00 0%, #ffffffcd 48%, #ffffff 100%) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
}

.vl-l {
  height: 92px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #edf6f7;
  margin-top: 14px;
}

.vl-r {
  height: 92px;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid #edf6f7;
  margin-top: 14px;
}

.FlexContainer-body {
  float: left;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.FlexContainer-body p {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.FlexContainer {
  margin-top: 23px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.FlexContainer div {
  margin: 9px;
}

.more-button {
  z-index: 1;
  background: #0b243c 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 35px;
  width: 210px;
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  font-size: 13px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: -30px;
}

.force_display {
  z-index: 9999;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

.FlexContainer-r {
  margin-top: 23px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  float: right;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.FlexContainer-r div {
  margin: 9px;
}

.FlexContainer-text {
  float: left;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.FlexContainer-text p {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<li className="conseil-card">
  <section className="FlexContainer-body">
    <section className="FlexContainer">
      <div>
        <IconAdd />
      </div>
      <div>
        <IconDrag />
      </div>
    </section>
    <div className="vl-l"></div>
    <section className="FlexContainer-text">
      <div className="force_display">
        <button className="more-button">
                       Afficher
                      </button>
      </div>
      <div className="conseil-card-pack">
        0Message conseil 2.1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras pulvinar sed augue non sodales. Sed orci ex, aliquam vel maximus ac, posuere eu ex. Sed et est felis.
      </div>
    </section>
    <div className="vl-r"></div>
    <section className="FlexContainer-r">
      <div>
        <IconStar />
      </div>
      <button className="icon_button modal-toggle">
                      <IconEdit />
                    </button>
    </section>
  </section>
</li>
```

In my div conseil-card-pack I have one ::after with blur. This is this width I want to render automatically.

If you need more code or other, please tell me.

Comment: Why you have `width:60%` for `.conseil-card-pack::after`? Set `position:relative` for `.conseil-card-pack` and use `width:100%;height:100%;` for your `:after` decoration element. Also, you can apply backdrop filter for real blur here.

Comment: There is no `blur` in your code

Comment: Please look carefully at your snippet and make sure that when we run it it shows the problem - at the moment there is not blurring at all.

Comment: Thanks you too much @350D its work ! the 60% is for i can see i pics !
Is not an blur, I have say blur because I have making an blur gradient with div. Sorry for this incomprehension.